# Moving Some Articles to new site

Tags: migration

I have a question about moving wordpress sites around. I've read most of the Support Docs about moving a wordpress site. My question is this, what would you guys recommend in regards to moving only certain posts from one site into a totally different domain. My current domain is a tech/blog installation. The past year or so, I've been posting my technical stuff to a different domain, and my current domain is collecting quite a bit of dust. What I'm wanting to do is turn my current domain into a personal blog and move only my technical articles over to the new blog.

Obviously, there's probably an easy way to move posts and comments over (i haven't looked into it but i'm pretty sure I can do this pretty easily). The true question is how I would present these posts on the current site once they are moved over to the new domain? Do I keep them on the current domain? Should I redirect users to the new domain automatically on only these posts? Should I remove them from the current site? These type of questions I'm wondering and if you guys have an pointers please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try the following:

```
site #1 == source
site #2 == destination
```

On the Site #1:

1. on all the post you want to move/migrate allocate them a category say 'moved'
2. export them using 'Tools' > 'Export' (select 'Posts' and specify categories 'moved')

On site #2:

1. Import your exported file using 'Tools' > 'Import' > 'WordPress' and follow the on screen instructions. You might also want to import related media or attachments.
2. remove 'moved' category in the category editor: 'Pots' > 'Categories'

back to site #1: put a redirect on migrated posts

1. install 'Redirection' WordPress plugin
2. now configure all the redirects for each post or moved category to redirect to your new site/posts.

Comment: Thanks.  I went ahead and used the Redirection wordpress plugin and that worked like a champ.